# Excel: Find if cell is >= or <= of an array of dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have made a dynamic calendar here: [Please copy and paste for testing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VoY-6_iUIy-tkIyFJoWpwDJSSaqewkugjG4qEtkwl_8/edit?usp=sharing)

The calendar currently uses `VLOOKUP` formulas (and more) to find guests checking into a property and lists information associated with their stay such as number of nights and their contact details. All of this is derived from a list shown to the right. Yes, it does contain

The date can be changed in cell B3 to the first of each month to view new guests checking in each month.

I now need to create conditional formatting formulas to alter the colour of the 3 cells spread across each day. You will see 7th December 2019 has the first cell in green, second white and 3rd red. I have created a formula to detect if  the date (always right most cell) is contained in the range `X5:AF13`. This formula will not work if the check-in date is any other day than a Saturday. The 'prototype' formulas created so far are illustrated below.

[image]

I need to construct a new formula that will work so the date (07, 08, 09 etc) is searched against the occupied days/nights in the range `X5:AF13` shown in pink. My proposed method is to cross reference (`VLOOKUP`) the date against the days/nights which the property is occupied for. I need to find the `SUM([Date2]+[Nights]-1)` to find the check-out date and somehow find if the date shown in the calendar is `>=` or `<=` to any of dates between check-on and check-on with the list in pink.

Is `VLOOKUP` the right forumla or is `MATCH` or even a combination with `IF(AND(` and `SUM(`? Slightly stuck...

[image]

Comment: I have answered the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58175322/conditional-format-cells-in-google-sheets-based-on-datex/58194686#58194686) you asked yesterday which is same to this one. You may add the updated information to your original post, and add the tags of this post to your last post. Then this post can be closed. Please note my answer is based on my experience in Excel, which I am not 100% sure it is also applicable in google-sheets. If my approach also works in google-sheets, please let me know just for my information. Thanks,

Comment: @TerryW this is superb help and I will take a good look at tidying things up in google sheets and the forum after work hours. Many thanks in advance